# Apache cxf Client call inside an EJB 2.0 SessionBean, BMT Error should complete transaction

Tags: apache, jboss, ejb, cxf

We are trying to consume a webservice from an EJB 2.0. The code for the client was created using soapUI with Apache CXF 2.7.6. 
The problem comes when we try to invoke the service from inside de EJB, getting an error:
"javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.RemoteException: Application error: BMT stateless bean ServiceBean should complete transactions before returning (ejb1.1 spec, 11.6.1)"

The ejb transaction is declared as

```
<session-type>Stateless</session-type>
<transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
```

We also tried to exclude de method calling the webservice from transaction

```
   <container-transaction>
  <method>
     <ejb-name>ServiceEJB</ejb-name>
      <method-name>*</method-name>
   </method>
   <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
</container-transaction>
   <container-transaction>
  <method>
     <ejb-name>ServiceEJB</ejb-name>
      <method-name>cxfServiceCall</method-name>
   </method>
   <trans-attribute>NotSupported</trans-attribute>
</container-transaction>
```

I was reading, is there any CXF incompatibility with EJB 2.0??
What may be wrong?

PS: We are using Jboss 4.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that you need to change the EJB transaction type from Bean to Container.

```
<transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
```